# Stop Access writing two sets of double quotes to csv

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

So, I'm using the output from a record set and writing out to a csv file. But I'm getting an issue with Quotation marks. Ideally I'd like to include them as text markers. But if I include them in my line of text they get printed as two sets of quotation marks.

I want this as the output (delimited by tabs):

> "Header1"    "header2"   "......[]...."headerX"

I tried this

```
Sub Write_Tbl(Filename, StrSQL)
Dim unicode, UTF, i As Long , Fileout As Object, forwriting,  TristateUseDefault, TxtStr As String, TextHolder As String, rs As Recordset

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim File_out As Object
Set File_out = fso.CreateTextFile(Filename, True, unicode = UTF - 8)
File_out.Close

Open Filename For Output As #1

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(StrSQL)
rs.MoveFirst

'for headers
    TxtStr = rs.Fields.Item(0).Name         'so that there isn't a tab at the start of the string

For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count - 1

TxtStr = TxtStr & chr(34) & vbTab & chr(34) & rs.Fields.Item(i).Name
Next i

Write #1, TxtStr & chr(34)          'write headers to file
```

and got this as the output

> ""Header1""    ""header2""   ""......[]....""headerX""

So I removed the quotation marks and got this:

```
'for headers
    TxtStr = rs.Fields.Item(0).Name         'so that there isn't a tab at the start of the string

For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count - 1

TxtStr = TxtStr & vbTab & rs.Fields.Item(i).Name
Next i

Write #1, TxtStr          'write headers to file
```

and what I'm getting is

> "Header1    header2   ......[]....headerX"

If I monitor the variables in the locals window, there's only one set of quotes so it must be something to do with printing? It doesn't happen if I use single quotation marks (ascii no 39). I also tried just using write to file, rather than as a text stream, but I got memory issues and [ERROR 5 issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680687/trying-to-write-text-to-a-file-error-5) STUMPED. Please help.

Comment: on another note, doing this: Dim unicode, UTF, i As Long  will dim only i as long, the others as variants, you need : 'Dim unicode As Long, UTF As Long, i As Long'

Comment: Thanks, it was actually my intention to do so, but for a long while coding in vba I had no idea that it worked like that, it's an excellent and widely undocumented point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have prepared your text string in VBA, you should use the `Print #` statement instead of `Write #` .

Documentation: [`Print #`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264278.aspx) vs. [`Write #`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264524.aspx)

> Unlike the **Print #** statement, the **Write #** statement inserts commas between items and quotation marks around strings as they are written to the file.

Note:

I'm not sure if these functions write Unicode at all, or care how the file was created.

```
Open Filename For Output As #1
```

will create the file if it doesn't exist, so you can probably omit the whole `CreateTextFile` part.

Or use `File_out.WriteLine()` instead, it seems odd to mix both methods (FSO and the ancient Print/Write statements).

Edit: see [How to create and write to a txt file using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba)

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.